# Extract first k characters of string in prolog

Tags: string, recursion, prolog

Well, I'm very new in prolog and I'm trying to solve some simple recursive problems like the following.

Implement `firstKCharacters(Str, K, L)` function which gets the first `K` characters of string `Str` in the result string `L`. I've figured out the following solution:

```
firstKCharacters(_, 0, _):- !.
firstKCharacters([X|L1], K, L):- append([X], S1, L),
    X1 is K - 1, firstKCharacters(L1, X1, S1).
```

I'm confused about result:

```
?- firstKCharacters([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], 1, X).
X = [a|_1174]
```

Can someone explain what is the `_1174` and why I'm getting `a|_1174` isntead of `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in the terminal version of `firstKCharacters/3`; writing

```
firstKCharacters(_, 0, _):- !.
```

you forget to fix the output list to a empty list; you should write it as follows

```
firstKCharacters(_, 0, []) :- !.
```

Without fixing it, remain a variable (the `_` in third position) that isn't unified: your `_1174`.

A (off topic, I suppose) suggestion: avoid `append` and simply translate `X` from the left to the right list. I mean: write the other version of `firstKCharacters/3` as follows

```
firstKCharacters([X|L1], K, [X|L]):-
    X1 is K - 1, firstKCharacters(L1, X1, L).
```

Because I donk like the cut, I propose you a version without it

```
firstKCharacters(_, 0, []).

firstKCharacters([X|L1], K, [X|L]):- 
    K > 0,
    Km1 is K - 1,
    firstKCharacters(L1, Km1, L).
```

Comment: Cool!! Thanks for explanation

Comment: No one likes the cut :)